# while using Google Maps Android API v2 got error Signature not valid. Found:

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, exception, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm creating sample application to use Google Maps Android API v2.

**I tried on Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i**, but instead of Map, I'm seeing

[image]

And logcat is

```
 Signature not valid.  Found: 
 MIIDDTCCAfWgAwIBAgIEEhX+gTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA3MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UE
 ChMHQW5kcm9pZDEWMBQGA1UEAxMNQW5kcm9pZCBEZWJ1ZzAeFw0xMzAyMjUxMTEwNDRaFw00MzAy
 MTgxMTEwNDRaMDcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRAwDgYDVQQKEwdBbmRyb2lkMRYwFAYDVQQDEw1BbmRy
 b2lkIERlYnVnMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApqChoDnHsDfsxa7n2Kv9
 2av0G0tm+kS1uP4T6fA8cO6jB3qB5EHFR6+5UO+k4laHW2WzOJbyhhtFE5eOTS4Zt5qo4FX/hsc/
 Zi7dDX/Y13b+4qajhLoGYqVjM00eQc2qF58TTnbQ3lTERxaofYL2qI3j2KcVODFMksinL9lt3RTD
 V3MXy7KDLcuSvoVZxXn1L0O9rkTbZicmleK4wLDzI+lTpuXngAuQ4MBH1wEWwqMhJg6/J06t5axU
 ea2UVv7ZtYg8KPMEiQEApCbdAHtQsmqcsEQZtJAqFtj7KEQ7wTSgnpDRix4N5C9QlwUtKSlOCIlk
 ueUPVBypKf/SWIgF6QIDAQABoyEwHzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQURyMuspjlLaDj8LhEb5UyYqQgWQYwDQYJ
 KoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAA9IXLEAQTD+VEt9l8JQDEOFv8WqIdQisvmJCfJjN98faarvf6RRA+v3
 HF2VFlZPaUu/HBeOH8MI7u+gNuRtZGYWn1eC/qfP0W31MQoNaN4ocsF+tL9INzpd89/u6Ya5Kove
 r0E0tpJFBgdtDPYcPBjQ6tYAqmhnmPIJftGHLNQbil4ocK/PkqgxGlwQN7WrCNjDewb0twz7hZBx
 Ig4OsnfdgPTYGlR+LyTzUd9/KyqaLHivRAI+y/xGDz6lOfGH7bDOPi/hDm0bkhC1y1J7L9+FiGWb
 dmi+Co9Jlf1f3vyTtD7kr3h0K0C3MsNWtybVqmVvgImoLt/lPbjNJahVrds=
 Google Play services signature invalid.
 Can't open keycharmap file
 Error loading keycharmap file
 Using default keymap
```

My manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.testmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.testmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.testmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDTsWrO0j24sbp4E5qhoHhd6nyOQM5lErc" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testmap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

my xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

My activity code

```
package com.example.testmap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.final_main);

    GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    //map.getMinZoomLevel();
}
}
```

And clicking on ok button gives force close with Logcat

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1374)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.e$2.onClick(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also when I UN-comment last line `map.getMinZoomLevel();` , I get null pointer exception on the line.

Comment: Are you trying to run your code on the emulator?

Comment: no, I'm trying on Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i

Comment: Do you have Google Maps and/or Google Play services installed on your device?

Comment: both Play Store and Google Maps works on the device

Comment: And you've defined the api key on google api console?

Comment: Open this url from Google Play and check if your device is compatible: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms .

Comment: @Marcelo please explain, where to open the url? from device's browser? or in play store?

Comment: @cmota yse I have, and the key generated there, used in manifest

Comment: @Marcelo I checked, Google Play Services is installed on the device

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on a GT-S5570I. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enabled offline work for gradle: Goto File > Settings > Gradle

Deselect Offline Work if its checked.

Then confirm if you have latest version of google services mentioned as dependencies in project level build.gradle:
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'

You can find latest version here: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/

Clean and build the project after gradle sync completes.
ouThese steps solved a similar issue I'd with Google Maps **and also solved the first error you mentioned** `Signature Not Valid`

If your device runs on Android M, you may want to verify your code for location access following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33579371/2115117) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same exception and I fixed it.

Note: I am working on google analytics and was getting this exception. But my app was not crashing I was getting this in Logs. you can also try this solution.

add this in project level gradle file.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'
```

and this one for module level gradle file.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

and move `below plugin at the end of file (at last line) of module level gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```