# How to provide the permission for android M to run the location in service?

Tags: android

I need to provide the permission for android M.what are the needs need to be used to provide the permission in service .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission issues for location in android Marshmallow applicaton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579280/permission-issues-for-location-in-android-marshmallow-applicaton)

Answer (score 0):

Basic location permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: The following permission are working below Api22 .The app gets crashed for Api 23.I need to know the structure and the method to provide permission for Api 23.Thanks ...