# Google Maps not working on device one plus one (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, google-maps

Why the maps and location not working on device one plus one (Marshmallow), but in other device (I try in Kitkat and lollipop it's working)? so that can't detect our location

[image]

this is my code

```
private void setMap() {
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(getApplicationContext(), data);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(place.getLatLng().latitude, place.getLatLng().longitude);
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
            }
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;

        this.googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

        GoogleMapOptions option = new GoogleMapOptions();
        option.compassEnabled(true);
        this.googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);

    }

    private OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            if(awal) {
                awal=false;
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a runtime permission of maps, Marshmallow need runtime permission of resources. Refer below link

[Permission issues for location in android Marshmallow applicaton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579280/permission-issues-for-location-in-android-marshmallow-applicaton)