# Code asking for permissions Multiple times on first launch

Tags: java, android, permissions

I edit some code to making an application to get mobile data its basic information. I am facing too issues.

1. Permissions are asked 3 times.
2. App is crashing in marshmallow on first launch with error of permission not for `access_coarse_location`.
   Advice how to fix the problem and what wrong is with this code.

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```

   ```
   import android.Manifest;
   import android.annotation.TargetApi;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.DialogInterface;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
   import android.os.Build;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.PersistableBundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
   import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
   import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

   import android.telephony.CellLocation;
   import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.List;
       import java.util.Map;
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 1;
       //Declaring View Object
       public TextView Info;
       public Button Refreshbtn;

       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)


       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           Refreshbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Refresh);
           Refreshbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   DeviceData();
               }
           });
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
               //Toast.makeText(this, "It is M Version", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Askpermission();

           } else {
               // Toast.makeText(this, "it is below M", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               DeviceData();
           }
       }

       private void Askpermission() {

           List<String> permissionlist = new ArrayList<String>();
           List<String> permissionneeded = new ArrayList<String>();
           if (addPermission(permissionlist, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
               permissionneeded.add("Location");
           if (addPermission(permissionlist, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
               permissionneeded.add("Location");
           if (addPermission(permissionlist, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS))
               permissionneeded.add("Send SMS");
           if (addPermission(permissionlist, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE))
               permissionneeded.add("Read Phone Info");


           if (permissionlist.size() > 0) {
               if (permissionneeded.size() > 0) {

                   for (int i = 1; i < permissionneeded.size(); i++)
                       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionlist.toArray(new String[permissionlist.size()]), REQUEST_PERMISSION);

               }
               return;
           }

           DeviceData();

       }

       @Override
       public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
           switch (requestCode) {
               case REQUEST_PERMISSION: {
                   Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                   // Initial
                   perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                   perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                   perms.put(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                   perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                   // Fill with results
                   for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                       perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                   // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                   if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                           && perms.get(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                           && perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                           && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                       // All Permissions Granted
                       DeviceData();
                   } else {
                       // Permission Denied
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                               .show();
                   }
               }
               break;
               default:
                   super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
           }
       }


       private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionlist, String permission) {
           if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               permissionlist.add(permission);
           }
           return true;

       }


       public void DeviceData() {

           Info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Info);


           //Creating object to use TelephonyManager Class methods to get required data.
           TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


           CellLocation Devicelocation = tm.getCellLocation();
           String DeviceId = tm.getDeviceId();
           String Devicecountry = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
           String Deviceoperator = tm.getNetworkOperator();
           String DeviceSimCountry = tm.getSimCountryIso();
           String Simoperator = tm.getSimOperator();
           String SimOperatorName = tm.getSimOperatorName();
           String simSerialNumber = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
           int Datanetwork = tm.getNetworkType();
           String DataNetworkType = "";
           String Softwareverion = tm.getDeviceSoftwareVersion();
           String PhoneType = "";
           int phonetype = tm.getPhoneType();
           int datastate = tm.getDataState();
           String DataState = "";
           switch (phonetype) {
               case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA):
                   PhoneType = "CDMA";
                   break;
               case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM):
                   PhoneType = "GSM";
                   break;

               case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE):
                   PhoneType = "NONE";
                   break;
           }
           switch (Datanetwork) {
               case (TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE):
                   DataNetworkType = "EDGE";
                   break;
               case (TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA):
                   DataNetworkType = "HSDPA";
                   break;

           }

           switch (datastate) {
               case (TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED):
                   DataState = "Data Disconnected";
                   break;
               case (TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTING):
                   DataState = "Data Connecting";
                   break;
               case (TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED):
                   DataState = "Data Connected";
                   break;
           }

           boolean isRoaming = tm.isNetworkRoaming();

           String AllDetails = "Phone Details:\n";

           AllDetails += "\n Device Location:" + Devicelocation;
           AllDetails += "\n Data Status:" + DataState;
           AllDetails += "\n Data Network Type:" + DataNetworkType;
           AllDetails += "\n Phone Type:" + PhoneType;
           AllDetails += "\n Device IMEI No.:(Id)" + DeviceId;
           AllDetails += "\n Device Country:" + Devicecountry;
           AllDetails += "\n Device Operator:" + Deviceoperator;
           AllDetails += "\n Device Sim Country:" + DeviceSimCountry;
           AllDetails += "\n Sim Operator:" + Simoperator;
           AllDetails += "\n Sim Operator Name:" + SimOperatorName;
           AllDetails += "\n Sim Serial Number:" + simSerialNumber;
           AllDetails += "\n Mobile Software Version:" + Softwareverion;
           AllDetails += "\n Roaming Status:" + isRoaming;

           Info.setText(AllDetails);
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Please add the "java" and "android" tag and post the manifest

Comment: I tried on few other devices like oneplus one and Mi Max and code is working fine with single time permissions. Do not know why asking multiple permission on my nexus 5 and emulator nexus 5. Pls help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579280/permission-issues-for-location-in-android-marshmallow-applicaton

Comment: Code is working fine now. I reinstalled app and everything working perfectly as expected. So want to close this query.